# Disposing of the subscription when observable completes

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

In a guide book for Angular 2 it says:

"The default behavior of Observable operators is to dispose of the subscription as soon as .complete() or .error() messages are published. Keep in mind that RxJS was designed to be used in a "fire and forget" fashion most of the time."

In an earlier page there's an example of observable and of subscription.

[example here](http://plnkr.co/edit/SA25mG?p=preview).

You can see there that after 3 seconds the onbservable ".complete()" 's. But when clicking again on the Init() button and invoking the init() method, the subscriber is still being informed. So what does the author means by saying 
**"dispose of the subscription"**?

Code:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Component({
    selector: 'app',
    template: `
      <b>Angular 2 Component Using Observables!</b>

      <h6 style="margin-bottom: 0">VALUES:</h6>
      <div *ngFor="let value of values">- {{ value }}</div>

      <h6 style="margin-bottom: 0">ERRORs:</h6>
      <div>Errors: {{anyErrors}}</div>

      <h6 style="margin-bottom: 0">FINISHED:</h6>
      <div>Finished: {{ finished }}</div>

      <button style="margin-top: 2rem;" (click)="init()">Init</button>
    `
})
export class MyApp {

  private data: Observable<Array<number>>;
  private values: Array<number> = [];
  private anyErrors: boolean;
  private finished: boolean;

  constructor() {
  }

  init() {
      this.data = new Observable(observer => {
          setTimeout(() => {
              observer.next(42);
          }, 1000);

          setTimeout(() => {
              observer.next(43);
          }, 2000);

          setTimeout(() => {
              observer.complete();
          }, 3000);
      });

      let subscription = this.data.subscribe(
          value => this.values.push(value),
          error => this.anyErrors = true,
          () => this.finished = true
      );
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because each time you click on the init you create a new observable. Try changing your line:

```
this.data = ...
```

to

```
if(!this.data){
  this.data = ...
```

and you will see that further invocations of `init` won't invoke the handler

Answer (score 0):

Move the creation of your Observable inside the constructor.

You can have a subject inside your constructor e.g.

```
constructor() {   
   super();   
   this.data$ = new Rx.Subject(); 
}
```

Then inside your click handler you can do something like:

`this.data.onNext(42)`

If you trigger the `onComplete`also manually you will have to check if the stream is completed before calling `onNext`

Answer (score 0):

When you are creating subscriptions on things like the location or router events the subscriptions keep existing event after your component is destroyed, which can lead to pretty hard to find errors and unwanted behavior.

When firing http calls the connection is closed after a successful transmission and your subscription will be closed, because the observable fires complete().

Here is an example of a code i have written lately:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    ...
    this.electionStateSubscription = this.electionState.getState()
            .subscribe((state: ElectionState) => this.state = state);
}

ngOnDestroy(): void {
    ...
    this.electionStateSubscription.unsubscribe();
}
```

In this example have built a redux like state store and am subscribing to it in this component. The `electionState` is always existing and never completes.

When this component gets destroyed the subscription is **disposed**. Otherwise this would create a new subscription every time the component is initialized which if nothing else bad happens can lead to performance problems.